# Django ImportError: No module named 'app'

Tags: python-3.4, django-1.8

I have been using `django 1.3` by now. But wanted to start with latest version `1.8.1` with `python3.4`I have started with the project.
Here is my directory structure:

```
├── myapp
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── home.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

*urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views 
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', "home", name='homepage'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def home(request):
    render(request, "home.html", {"text":"Hello World!!!"})
```

settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'common',
)
```

Getting following error on runserver

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'common'
```

Comment: @dhke - I just created `python manage.py startproject myapp`. I don't think it is wrong. I had tried it before it worked with success.

Comment: I was just trying to reformulate the comment, sorry about that ;-). All django projects I have, have `manage.py` at the top level project directory and I'm also pretty sure that's where django roots the app search path. So in your case, `common` is actually at `myapp.common` from django's point of view. No idea why that has worked before, however.

Comment: @dheke-  Your suggestion was correct. could you please make it as an answer. Thanks for efforts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path of `manage.py` looks unusual to me. `manage.py` is usually at the top level project directory. The problem you encounter stems from the fact that django roots the search path (i.e. `sys.path`) at the path of the `manage.py` script.

In your case, `common`'s relative module path is actually `myapp.common`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp.common',
)
```

Of course `myapp` is then actually the *project* in django lingo.